# Graphical representation of vector equation

Tags: graphics, vector

Hi I want to to show graphically:

$$\vec{x} = \vec{p} + t(\vec{q}-\vec{p})$$ 
for vectors $\vec{x},\vec{p},\vec{q}$ and t varying from 0 to 1 in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  So basically the vector $\vec{x}$ goes along line segment between P and Q.  Obviously I could define specific vectors $\vec{p}$ and $\vec{q}$.  How could I do this?

BTW how do I type latex in this forum?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bit code that produces an animation of what you described:

```
org = {0, 0};
p = {5, 1}; q = {2, 6};
pvec = {Red, Arrow[{org, p}]};
qvec = {Blue, Arrow[{org, q}]};
Animate[Show[
  Graphics[{pvec, qvec, {Black, Arrow[{org, p + t (q - p)}]}}, 
   Frame -> True],
  ImageSize -> 150], {t, 0, 1}]
```

If you want to see an image at a specific value of $t$, at $t=1/3$ maybe, you could use this:

```
Show[
  Graphics[{pvec, qvec, {Black, Arrow[{org, p + t (q - p)}]}}, 
   Frame -> True],
  ImageSize -> 150] /. t -> 1/3
```

Instead of Latex we use something similar called [Markdown](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).  That link will be useful in learning how to format questions and answers on this site.  The link is part of the [Help Center](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help), which you may also find useful.